# pointer to array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I'm wondering, can you make a pointer to a group of variables in an array?
like this

```
array[20]{'a','b','c',...}
pointer = array[6 through 10];
```

so then you could say...

```
*pointer[0] == array[6];
```

and

```
*pointer[5] == array[10];
```

and the length of *pointer

```
5 == sizeof(*pointer) \ sizeof(type);
```

### OK

Let me explain what I'm trying to accomplish, maybe that will clear me up a bit.
I want to read a full file into a buffer, but I want to do it piece by piece. passing a small array into read() and then looping it into the larger array defeats the purpose. I was hoping that I could directly 'point' to an area in the buffer I want to fill, and pass that to the read() function.

#### I DO NOT want to use streams or anything that buffers behind my back

that would be counterproductive as I'm trying read the whole file into memory at once. As fast as possible.

### I need speed!!!

Comment: Just to get it out of the way, there's no way you can make `sizeof(pointer) / sizeof(*pointer)` (which is what I assume you meant by that last line) equal the array length. That's simply not how pointers work.

Comment: Do you have a large enough buffer allocated?  If you're sure that your buffer is 'big enough to read the whole file', you can read the whole file in one `fread` call.  If you want no buffering, look at `setvbuf()`, but *test* unbuffered first input to see if it's faster!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Despite what everyone has said, this *is* possible, with one small caveat - unless you have a C99 compiler, you have to know the size of the "slice" that you want at compile time.

To declare and use the pointer correctly, you also have to know that the subscript operator `[]` binds before the `*` dereference operator, so parantheses are needed.

Behold:

```
int array[20] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l'};
int (*pointer)[10 - 6 + 1] = (int (*)[10 - 6 + 1])&array[6];    /* = array[6 through 10] */

printf("(*pointer)[0] = %c\n", (*pointer)[0]);
printf("(*pointer)[4] = %c\n", (*pointer)[4]);
printf("sizeof *pointer / sizeof **pointer = %lu\n", (unsigned long)(sizeof *pointer / sizeof **pointer));
```

**Addendum:**

For the answer to your *actual* problem that you've put in, that's a lot easier.  Just use a pointer that is set to an offset from the buffer array, eg:

```
unsigned char buffer[102400];
unsigned char *ptr;

/* ... */
ptr = buffer + 500;
read(fd, ptr, 1024); /* Try and read up to 1024 bytes at position buffer[500] */
```

Comment: I most defiantly know the 'slice', it never changes. This may be what I was looking for.

Comment: Nice answer!  C99's `(T (*)[N]) a` idiom is useful, thanks. +1.

Comment: The above snippet is even valid C89 (because `10 - 6 + 1` is a compile-time constant) - you'd need C99 if the `10` and/or the `6` were obtained from variables, though.

Comment: caf: can you quote the standard where it says this is valid?  I think it's implementation defined.

Comment: As far as I can see, the relevant parts are 6.2.5 p20 (where an array type is a *contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects* - padding is not allowed) and 6.3.2.3 p7 (where a pointer must point to the lowest addressed byte of the object).  That is, it works for the reason that both `sizeof a / sizeof a[0]` give the number of elements in an array, and that `int (*a)[10] = malloc(20 * sizeof *a);` gives a valid pointer.

Comment: But `pointer` is a pointer to "array[5] of int", whereas `array+6` is of type `int *`.  6.3.2.3p7 says, "When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a *character* type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object."  `int (*)[5]` is not a pointer to a character object. The same section, previous two lines say: "If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the pointed-to type, the behavior is undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the original pointer." I am not sure if `int (*)[5]` is correctly aligned.

Comment: ...and even if it is, *...when converted back again, ...* part only says that the converted pointer must compare equal, nothing about dereferencing them.

Answer (score 6):

Sure enough you can.

```
int a[4] = {1,2,3,4};
int *b = &a[2];
cout << b[0] << "-" << b[1] << endl;
```

The output will be 3-4.

Comment: am I the only person who thinks &a[i] looks sloppy? its equivalent to &(*(a + i)) which is much easier to write as a + i

Answer (score 4):

In the below example I've declared a static array of 10x ints. I've created 2 pointers to it's elements - thus defining a range. What I did next was : I declared a pointer in the for loop starting with the pointer p1 which went through every item in the array until it reached pointer p2 - printing item's value.

Is that what you were looking for?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    int a[10] = { 0, 4, 5, 7, 4, 3, 1, 6, 2, 9 };

    int *p1 = &a[3];
    int *p2 = &a[7];

    for(int *p = p1; p != p2; ++p)
    {
        cout << *p << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My bad. I'm too rusty for my own good. I read too fast and misread the code. For some reason I thought `p` pointed to `p1` and not to `&a[3]`. Silly me. I apologize for the downvote (but I can't retract it because of the moronic 2-second limit on changing votes).

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, you can easily do the first part.  Just do `pointer = array + 6`.  But what is `pointer`?  It *cannot* be declared as:

```
char pointer[5];
```

or similar.  It has to be a *pointer*:

```
char *pointer = array + 6;
```

This is because you can't assign an array to some other name (an array is not a modifiable l-value).  It does not make sense to say:

```
char a[10];
char b[10];
b = a;
```

Now, in C, the size of a pointer is just the size of the pointer—since a pointer does not have a notion of "the number of units" of a given type pointed to.  Arrays, on the other hand, know exactly how many elements they have, and you can get that size by an appropriate use of the `sizeof` operator.

So, `sizeof array` in your example would be 10 (if it has 10 elements), whereas `sizeof pointer` is going to be the number of bytes occupied by a `char` pointer.  **Therefore, what you ask in the second part of your question is impossible in C**.  In C++, you have access to data types that should allow you to do what you want.

*Edit*: To read a file in chunks:

Let's say you have a big buffer, that you're sure you can read the whole file into:

```
unsigned char bigbuf[1UL << 24]; /* or whatever you want */
unsigned char *ptr = bigbuf;
size_t chunk = BUFSIZ;
FILE *fp = fopen("foo.txt", "rb"); /* no error checking */
size_t nread;
size_t total = 0;
while ((nread = fread(ptr, 1, chunk, fp)) > 0) {
    ptr += nread;
    total += nread;
    if (total + chunk > sizeof bigbuf) {
        /* oops, not enough space */
    }
}
if (ferror(fp)) {
    /* read error */
} else {
    /* bigbuf now has data, total has the number of bytes */
}
```

For unbuffered I/O, look at `setvbuf()`.  But test buffered and unbuffered inputs to see which one is faster.  Test different read sizes too.

Now an aside, which I had put in before, and I guess I will leave it in here anyway:

Having answered this question, more interesting is doing it *the other way*, i.e., given:

```
T a[10];
```

for any type `T`, can you declare `pointer` such that:

```
pointer[1] == a[0]
pointer[2] == a[1]
...
pointer[11] == a[10]
```

(or if you're feeling adventurous, replace 1 by a bigger positive number on the LHS of the first statement).

The answer, according to the C standard, is [no](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/non0based.html).  As mentioned in the link, *Numerical Recipes in C* made use of this 'trick'.

As an aside, I think you meant

```
pointer[0] == array[6];
```

and not

```
*pointer[0] == array[6];
```

in your question (similarly for `*pointer[5]`)

Answer (score 3):

You can have a pointer pointing to any element of a C array. Since C arrays do not "know" their length, the idea of a "range" of a C array cannot be expressed directly. As you have to store the length of the array itself, so you have to store the length of the range the pointer points to.

Comment: C arrays *do* know their length.  That is why I can do: int a[] = { 1, 2, 3}; sizeof a / sizeof a[0]; and get 3.

Comment: @Alok: But you can't write a function that takes arrays of different sizes, without passing the size explicitly.

Comment: int function(char * a, int *b)
{
  return sizeof(a) \ sizeof(char);
}

Comment: or you could use malloc(randomsize)

Comment: @DevSolar, yes, I am not talking about VLAs.  @unwind, when you pass an array to a function, it "decays" to a pointer, and is no longer an array.  In other words, the function only sees the pointer to the first element of the array.  @kelton, your "function" will always return the size of a char * pointer.

Comment: @kelton, that won't work. You're just going to get back the size of the pointer in bytes. You can only use the sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]) in the same scope that you declared arr (ie you can't take it as a parameter).

Comment: Just to add a little more noise into the discussion: In C you cannot, in C++ you can: `void f( int (&a)[10] );` will take only arrays of 10 integer elements. If you move the 10 into a template argument then you have a function (family of functions thereof) that will take arrays with a known size. This is used to obtain the size of an array: `template <typename T, std::size_t N> std::size_t array_size( T (&)[N] ) { return N; }` and can be further tweaked into providing a compile time constant if needed.

Answer (score 3):

a pointer points to a single memory location, so while, as others have said you can get a pointer to point to a location in the middle of an array

```
char *p = array + 6;
```

you need to express the allowed range some other way i.e. by passing a max length. or a second pointer

its probably worth pointing out that

```
array[i]
```

is identical to

```
*(array + i)
```

Answer (score 2):

`pointer = &array[6]`. `pointer[0]` will now reference the same value as `array[6]`. It's not directly possible to extract a reference to a slice of an array and keep `sizeof` semantics for it. You can emulate it with something like this:

```
template <class T>
class Slice {
public:
 Slice(T* elements, int begin, int end) : m_elements(elements + begin), m_size(end - begin) {}
 T& operator[] (int index) {return m_elements[index];}
 int size() const {return m_size;}
private:
 T* m_elements;
 int m_size; 
};

int values[10];
Slice<int> slice(values, 5, 10);
values[5] = 3;
assert(slice[0] == values[5]);
assert(slice.size() == 5);
```

Comment: Yes it is: `auto &slice = *reinterpret_cast<int (*)[5]>(&values[5]);` (I think).  If you don't have C++11, like when this was written, I think you can use `int (&slice)[5]` as the alias declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you use the addresses correctly:

```
int* ptr = new int[10];
int* ptrSub = &ptr[5];
```

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question you want to address a range of elements in the original array, a slice so to say.

In C++ you can do that easily - provided you implement your own arrayclass (keeping a pointer + number elements). Then you can define memberfunctions which will give you back a slice: a pointer into the original array and a number of elements such that you will not address outside the original array.

In Plain-Old-C you cannot have to sized arrays sharing storage and a pointer is unbounded by definition: it just points at a single element. You cannot let the C-code "re-interpret" a sized array since the *name* of the array (the symbol) is the address of the storage, which you cannot modify.

What you want is this:

```
int  array1[10];
int  array2[3];

// reference 3 elements from array1, starting at element 5 in array1
array2 = array1[5];
```

but that is not allowed. The name "array2" is translated by the compiler into a fixed address which you cannot redefine at runtime - that's why there are pointers: of those you can change whatever they point to at will at runtime.

Comment: You can do it in C++ without making an adapter class; see my comment in [Andreas Brinck](http://stackoverflow.com/users/125672/andreas-brinck)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1906254/1010226).

Answer (score -1):

Pointers only 'point' to the first item in any structure or variable. They are only an address. You could imply a range by making them a pointer to a specific type which identifies a range.

Comment: so basically
face somearray[6];
typedef face miniarray;
miniarray *a = &mainarray[3];